# Problema com brmask no Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic, mask

Além dessa máscara ja tentei utilizar outras duas que resultaram no mesmo erro, que é o seguinte:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute
Error: More than one custom value accessor matches form control with unspecified name attribute
```

Esse é o item que contem o problema:

```
 <ion-item>
  <ion-label color="primary" position = "floating" >CPF</ion-label>
  <ion-input  [(ngModel)] = "usuario.cpf" [brmasker]="000.000.000-00"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Modulo :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    BrMaskerModule
  ],
  declarations: [CadastrarPage]
})
```

segue o TypeScript completo, como solicitado:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { UsuarioService } from 'src/app/services/usuario.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-cadastrar',
  templateUrl: './cadastrar.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cadastrar.page.scss'],
})

export class CadastrarPage implements OnInit {

  resultado : any = {
    nome          : false,
    apelido       : false,
    sexo          : false,
    estado_civil  : false,
    email         : false,
    cpf           : false,
    celular       : false,
    dt_nascimento : false,
    password      : false
  }
  usuario : any = {}

  constructor(
    private modalCtrl : ModalController,
    private usuarioService : UsuarioService,
    private alertController : AlertController
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fechar()
  {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss()
  }

  async cadastrar()
  {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header:   'ERRO',
      message:  'Houve um erro, tente nvoamente mais tarde.',
      buttons:  ['OK']
    })

    this.usuarioService.incluir(this.usuario).subscribe(
      data => {
        if(data.status == 200)
        {
          this.resultado = data.body
        }
      },
      err => {
        alert.present()
      }
    )

  }
```

}

e o HTML :

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>cadastrar</ion-title>
    <ion-button (click)="fechar()" icon-only><ion-icon name="arrow-back"></ion-icon></ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>



    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position = "floating" >Nome</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="nome" [(ngModel)] = "usuario.nome" name="nome"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf ="resultado.nome">
        <ion-label color="danger">{{resultado.nome}}</ion-label>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position = "floating" >Apelido</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="apelido" [(ngModel)] = "usuario.apelido"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf ="resultado.apelido">
        <ion-label color="danger">{{resultado.apelido}}</ion-label>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position = "floating" >Sexo</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="sexo" [(ngModel)] = "usuario.sexo"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf ="resultado.sexo">
        <ion-label color="danger">{{resultado.sexo}}</ion-label>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position = "floating" >Estado Civil</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="estado_civil" [(ngModel)] = "usuario.estado_civil"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf ="resultado.estado_civil">
        <ion-label color="danger">{{resultado.estado_civil}}</ion-label>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position = "floating">E-mail</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="email" [(ngModel)] = "usuario.email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf ="resultado.email">
        <ion-label color="danger">{{resultado.email}}</ion-label>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position = "floating" >CPF</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="cpf" [(ngModel)] = "usuario.cpf" [brmasker]="000.000.000-00"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf ="resultado.cpf">
        <ion-label color="danger">{{resultado.cpf}}</ion-label>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position = "floating" >Celular</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="celular" [(ngModel)] = "usuario.celular"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf ="resultado.celular">
        <ion-label color="danger">{{resultado.celular}}</ion-label>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Data de Nascimneto</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime name="dt_nascimento" [(ngModel)] = "usuario.dt_nascimento" displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY" min="1994-03-14" max="2012-12-09" value=""></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf ="resultado.dt_nascimento">
        <ion-label color="danger">{{resultado.dt_nascimento}}</ion-label>
    </div>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-label color="primary" position="floating">Senha</ion-label>
      <ion-input name="password" [(ngModel)]="usuario.password" type="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <div *ngIf="resultado.senha">
      <ion-label color="danger">{{resultado.password}}</ion-label>
    </div>

    <ion-button (click)="cadastrar()">Cadastrar</ion-button>

</ion-content>
```

Obs: se eu utilizar o [brmasker] num input sem o ngModel nesta mesma pagina, funciona perfeitamente

Comment: E o seu arquivo **TS** está como?

Comment: Por isso pedi para mostrar seu TS, você não está utilizando o plugin conforme a documentação recomenda, o correto aí é utilizar **FormControl** ou então utilizar a versão anterior do plugin como o Vinicius disse na resposta mais abaixo.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Siga as etapas abaixo com atenção para resolver seu problema:

1. Remova os pacotes que você instalou até o momento para formatação, para isso utilize o comando npm rm nome-pacote;
2. Feito isso instale o seguinte pacote: https://github.com/amarkes/br-mask, essa é uma versão da br-mask que possui compatibilidade com ionic4, para instalar execute o comando abaixo:

   npm install br-mask --save -E
3. No arquivo module da page, (no meu caso grupos.module.ts) onde você deseja utilizar a mascara, importe o BrMaskerModule, vai ficar parecido com o exemplo abaixo, perceba que neste exemplo estou utilizando Reactive Forms, que é a orientação da equipe do Ionic, (fonte: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/developer-resources/forms/):

```html
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { GruposPage } from './grupos.page';
import { BrMaskerModule } from 'br-mask';



const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: GruposPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    ReactiveFormsModule, /* Para trabalhar com Reactive Forms Rapha */
    BrMaskerModule
    
  ],
  declarations: [GruposPage]
})
export class GruposPageModule {}
```

4. Agora basta aplicar a mascara, mas fique atento ao nome do formulário, pois no momento de aplicar a mascara, você vai precisar utilizar um formulario.get... onde formulario é o nome do seu form, veja como fica abaixo a uma mascara de CPF, (grupos.page.html):

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Grupo</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

  <form [formGroup]="formulario" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>CPF</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" name="cpf" formControlName="cpf" placeholder="CPF" [brmasker]="{form: formulario.get('cpf'), mask: '999.999.999-99'}"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!formulario.valid">Enviar</button>
  </form>


</ion-content>
```

5. E olha por fim como ficou o arquivo grupos.page.ts

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-grupos',
  templateUrl: './grupos.page.html',
})
export class GruposPage implements OnInit {

  private formulario : FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
      cpf: ['', Validators.required],
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  logForm(){
    console.log(this.formulario.value)
  }

}
```

Comment: Fiz login só pra agradecer. Obrigado!

Comment: Obrigado fico feliz em ter ajudado!!! :)

Comment: Funcionou!!!!!!!

Comment: Que legal!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Ao utilizar `[(ngModel)]` você precisa definir o atributo `name`.

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
<ion-input name="cpfUsuario"  [(ngModel)] = "usuario.cpf" [brmasker]="000.000.000-00"></ion-input>
```

Comment: Fiz a alteração porém ainda não surgiu efeito no erro

Comment: Tem mais algum lugar na sua página que utiliza o [(ngModel)] = "usuario.cpf" ? ou o name que você colocou?
Posta o seu arquivo TS, fica mais fácil ajudar

Comment: Segue agora o html e o typeScript ambos completos, percebi que o resultado pode ficar 'nebuloso' a primeira vista, então já adianto que a variavel resultado é setada de acordo com o retorno da minha API com a validação dos campos passados via POST, esta validação é retornada com status 200 pois se tudo ocorrer bem, os dados serão armazenados e receberei um status 201, podendo assim saber quando exibir os erros em cada campo especifico, ou não exibir (:

Comment: Não consegui encontrar problemas, talvez seja nesse pacote brmasker. Já tentou o ngx mask? Utilizo ele aqui e vai te atender bem

Comment: Foi o primeiro que tentei, ocorreu o mesmo erro, o que me levou a utilizar o brmask porém como ambos me deixaram no mesmo lugar cheguei a conclusão de que o erro poderia ser outra coisa... Por isso postei aqui

Comment: Gera esse erro ai no ngxMask mesmo utilizando o atributo name?

Answer (score 0):

Eu tive o mesmo problema, e minha solução foi utilizar um outro plugin chamado [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask).

Mas eu não consegui usar o `[(ngModel)]`. Para resolver como atualizar os valores numa variável, no botão eu adicionei `[disabled]="validaCPF(cpf)"` e adicionando `#cpf` no `ion-input` com a mascara aplicada, e depois no método `validaCPF` eu salvei o novo valor e retornei o resultado de uma simples validação.

Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label color="primary" position = "floating" >CPF</ion-label>
   <ion-input #cpf name="cpf" mask="000.000.000-00"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

...

<ion-button (click)="cadastrar()" [disabled]="validaCPF(cpf.value)">Cadastrar</ion-button>
```

E no seu arquivo `.ts`:

```
public validaCPF(cpf: string): boolean {
    this.usuario.cpf = cpf;

    return cpf.length === 0;
}
```

Comment: Testei dessa maneira e está acontecendo o mesmo erro, segue minha versão do brmask :  "brmasker-ionic-3": "^1.6.3",

Comment: Eu conferi num projeto meu,e eu havia confundido os plugins, agora eu corrigi a resposta com um plugin que funcionou comigo.